# What is the running time complexity of this algorithm? is it O(n)?

Tags: big-o

I just wanna know if this algorithm is O(n).

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(a[i]%10==0){
        temp=a[i];
        i++;
        while(a[i]%10!=0){
            a[i]=temp;
            i++;
        }
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: The algorithm increases `i` without bound in the inner loop. This can lead to accessing the array out of bounds, which is not allowed.

Comment: What is this code trying to accomplish?

Comment: please dont forget to pick a best answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is O(n). If all values in `a` are not multiples of 10 it is a regular for loop. If the `while` loop is entered, any iterations in the `while` loop are skipped in the `for` loop, meaning they don't cost extra time. So yes it will always be O(n).

That being said, I recommend not modifying your iteration variable in a place other than the `for` declaration. It makes the code hard to follow and bug-prone.